Reducing padding-top in a react native bottom tab navigator
Following is a screenshot of a react native bottom tab navigator. I've been trying to reduce the padding above the icons (marked in blue) but the padding property probably doesn't work in tab navigators.
As a workaround I added the height property to the tab navigator which sort of worked, in the sense that, the bottom padding reduced due to the change but the padding at the top remained unaffected.

Kindly note that I even tried reducing the navigator's height to barely accommodate the height of the icons along with a margin bottom but even then the icons only get cut from bottom while the padding at the top remains unchanged.

Try this tabBarOptions={{         style: { paddingTop: 0 }, // Set paddingTop to 0       }}

If there are no other answers, I can suggest you to rewrite the "container" component and specify it inside <Tab.Navigator />:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar
BTW: did you try to remove both padding and margin? Are you sure it's not the tabBarIcon causing that padding?
